# Каталог битрикс 1с выводит, что товара нет в наличии, хотя он есть

Tags: битрикс

Я создал интернет-магазин. В инфоблоке в торговом каталоге->параметры прописал количество, но на всех карточках пишется, что "нет в наличии". В чем может быть проблема? Буду рад любой помощи